# How to flash a message from Passport.js?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I've created login and register with express and passport js.
I want to add a message for wrong password or email.

in my index.js (main) added passport and body parser middleware with referring to the routes :

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// route files
let index = require("./routes/index");
let auth = require("./routes/auth");
app.use("/", index);
app.use("/auth", auth);
```

and I created passport configuration :

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const User = require("../models/User");
const config = require("../config/database");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

module.exports = function(passport) {
  // Local Strategy
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "email",
        passwordField: "password"
      },
      (username, password, done) => {
        // Match Email
        let query = { email: username };
        User.findOne(query, function(err, user) {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: "No user found" });
          }

          // Match Password
          bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (isMatch) {
              return done(null, user);
            } else {
              return done(null, false, { message: "Wrong password" });
            }
          });
        });
      }
    )
  );

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
};
```

also added a route for it :

```
// Login Process
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/auth/login",

    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

the successRedirect and failureRedirect work fine, but it doesn't give me any error. I did it on a youtube video in the video it works but in my code it doesn't.

configuration of connect flash :

```
const flash = require("connect-flash");
app.use(require("connect-flash")());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code, its just the version of express you are using. From the Passportjs Flash Message documentation,

Note: Using flash messages requires a **req.flash()** function. Express 2.x provided this functionality, however it was removed from Express 3.x. Use of connect-flash middleware is recommended to provide this functionality when using Express 3.x.

So you need to install **connect-flash** express middleware as it is recommended.

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
  app.use(flash());
});
```

With the flash middleware in place, all requests will have a req.flash() function that can be used for flash messages.

```
app.get('/flash', function(req, res){
  req.flash('info', 'Flash is back!')
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { messages: req.flash('info') });
});
```

This might help you.

Comment: I've installed it and used it for other flash messages using req.flash() but I don't know how to use it here

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash. Here you can find the example of to use connect-flash.

Comment: I understand I have used it in this project but I using it does not work in the failure flash even using another routee

Comment: Show me your configuration and usage of that library.

Comment: I added it in the question

Comment: thanks the problem is in the connect-flash, but I can't find a way to fix it

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't quite see the point of configuring 
`app.use()` with require. Just call the `flash()` method inside `app.use()` like this in your configuration.

```
var flash = require("connect-flash");
app.use(flash());
```

What you're missing is `req.flash("error")`. Because when a failure occurs passport passes the `message` object as `error`.

> [Passport Authenticate](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/)
>
> Setting the `failureFlash` option to true instructs Passport to flash an
>   `error` message using the message given by the strategy's verify
>   callback, if any.

This code is working at my end and passing req.flash() messages.

**routes.js**

```
//route for passport strategy
    router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local-signin", {
        failureRedirect: "/error",
        failureFlash: true,
    }));

//route for error page
router.get("/error", function(req, res, next) {
    res.render("error", {
        error: req.flash("error"),
    });
});
```

On the view side now you have access to `error` object hence can use it for view.
In my `error.hbs` handlebars view I do this.

**error.hbs**

```
{{#if error}}
    {{error}}
//Wrong password or No User Found
{{/if}}
<p>No results to show.</p>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler route to display success / failure flash messages:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate("local", 
    {
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/auth/login",
        successFlash: true,            
        failureFlash: true,
        successFlash: 'Succesfu1!',
        failureFlash: 'Invalid username or passwerd.'
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To return message without using flash option, change your post method like this

```
router.post('/users/signin', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      // *** Display message without using flash option
      res.status(500).send({ message: info.message });
    } else {
      // *** Display message without using flash option
      res.status(200).send({ message: 'success' });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```